# Aligning radiobuttonlist in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, radiobuttonlist

I have a aspx.vb code fragment which looks like this! (I am reading contents from xml config file to create radiobuttonlist)

```
Dim tr As TableRow = New TableRow

Dim tcValue As TableCell = New TableCell

Dim RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList

//After this I load all the items in radiobuttonlist

tcValue.Controls.Add(tdRadioButtonList)

tr.Cells.Add(tcValue)
```

Imagine this radiobuttonlist has 6 items.I want to create 2 columns which shoud consist of 3 radiobutton elements in each column and in a single row. How Can I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're so keen to make a custom list, why not make a table and have something like this, having a list/array of RadioButtons instead of one RadioButtonList object:

(Sorry, I don't use VB except to scrape something together in Access, so you'll have to make do with my C#, which you should be able to interpret fairly easily)

```
RadioButton[] items = getAllItems();

int i = 0;
Table table = new Table();
TableRow currentRow;

foreach(RadioButton item in items)
{
   if(i != 0)
      table.Rows.Add(currentRow);
   if(i++ % 2 == 0)
      currentRow = new TableRow();
   currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell()
      {
         Controls.Add(item)
      });
}

if(currentRow.Cells.Count != 0)
   table.Rows.Add(currentRow);

Page.Controls.Add(table);
```